# oracle sql select with employeees

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function

i have one interesting question, and could not resolve it. Please help!!!!

They are  tables

```
t_employee
   ID             NUMBER,
  DEPARTMENT_ID  NUMBER,
  CHIEF_ID       NUMBER,
  NAME           VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  SALARY         NUMBER,
  BIRTH_DATE     DATE,
  ADDRESS        VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  STATUS         VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
```

and

```
t_department
  ID    NUMBER,
  NAME  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
```

Need display the number of employees in each region - in Adress column (if they are now region then = 'No' area).
Names of areas converted to uppercase.

What is problem? Problem is that adress collumn has unstructured data for example:
Adress:

```
Country,REGION,city,...
```

So REGION always must be beetween first (,) and second (,) AND must include word (reg) 
For example:

```
Russia(Country), reg Moskovskay ,  Moscow(city), Lenina, (street)  .... or 
Russia(Country), Moskovskay reg ,  Moscow(city), Lenina, (street)  .... or
```

separator is (,)
position is - second

Many thanks!

Comment: offtopic, but bad table design...

Comment: What is your expected output? Could you please put it in a tabular format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free form strings are seldom a good idea in databases, this query won't be able to use indexes which will most likely make it a slow performer;

```
WITH a AS ( SELECT TRIM(
                    REPLACE(
                     UPPER(
                      REGEXP_SUBSTR(ADDRESS, ',([^,]*),', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
                     ), 
                     ' REG ', ''
                    )
                   ) REGION
            FROM t_employee)
SELECT REGION, COUNT(*) cnt FROM a GROUP BY REGION
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0e5b/2).

Comment: A very comprehensive answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(address, ',(.*?reg.*?),', 1, 1, null, 1) AS region, COUNT(*)
FROM t_employee
GROUP BY regexp_substr(address, ',(.*?reg.*?),', 1, 1, null, 1);
```

I would strongly advise however to refactor the schema and break the address into separate fields for street, city, region, etc. before or during table load, if only you have the possibility to do so.

Comment: This one also gives the required solution in a short amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

At the outset , please explore to see and change the database design to separate these fields.It will help you in the long run.If you would still want to stick on to this structure , you could manage the data in the required format while inserting itself.Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t_employee AS (
   SELECT 1 AS id, 10 AS department_id, 'a' AS name, 'kws, aaa reg, skdir, 23049' AS address FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 2, 10, 'b', 'slkx, aaa reg, lskdj, 902349' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 3, 20, 'c', 'lskj, bbb reg, lskdi, 489308' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 4, 10, 'd', 'lskj, aaa reg, lskdi, 489308' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 5, 20, 'e', 'lskj, ccc reg, lskdi, 489308' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 6, 30, 'f', 'lskj, bbb reg, lskdi, 489308' FROM dual
)
, t_region AS (
SELECT id,
       TRIM (
             REPLACE (
                       SUBSTR (address,
                               INSTR (address, ',', 1) + 1,
                               INSTR (address, ',', INSTR(address, ',', 1) + 1)
                                                  - INSTR(address, ',', 1) - 1),
                      'reg',
                      '')
            )
       AS region
  FROM t_employee e
)
  SELECT r.region, count(*) AS employees
    FROM t_region r
GROUP BY r.region
;
```

Comment: it is very hard is think!